# Duplicates while publishing data to kafka topic using spark-streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-producer-api, spark-streaming-kafka

I have spark-streaming application which consumes data from topic1 and parse it then publish same records into 2 processes one is into topic2 and other is to hive table. while publishing data to kafka topic2 I see duplicates and i don't see duplicates in hive table

using 
spark 2.2, Kafka 0.10.0

```
KafkaWriter.write(spark, storeSalesStreamingFinalDF, config)
writeToHIVE(spark, storeSalesStreamingFinalDF, config)


object KafkaWriter {

  def write(spark: SparkSession, df: DataFrame, config: Config)
  {
    df.select(to_json(struct("*")) as 'value)
      .write
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", config.getString("kafka.dev.bootstrap.servers"))
      .option("topic",config.getString("kafka.topic"))
      .option("kafka.compression.type",config.getString("kafka.compression.type"))
      .option("kafka.session.timeout.ms",config.getString("kafka.session.timeout.ms"))
      .option("kafka.request.timeout.ms",config.getString("kafka.request.timeout.ms"))
      .save()
  }
}
```

Can some one help on this,

Expecting no duplicates in kafka topic2.

Comment: Did you resolve?

Comment: Not yet, handling duplicates while consuming . Still looking for an option to eliminate while publishing

Answer (score 1):

To handle the duplicate data ,we should set the `.option("kafka.processing.guarantee","exactly_once"`)

Comment: This didn't help, I still see duplicates